# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes obtaining the mean distance of BallTree Neighbors of sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm getting the error "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (4,)" when I try to obtain the mean distance of the neighborhood of 50 points. The distance of the neighborhood is calculated using the function BallTree of sklearn. The query of this function is returning a numpy double array with the distance between the central point and the neighborhood, and I'm searching to get the mean distances between the central point and the neighborhood.

The code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.neighbors

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
X = rng.random_sample((50, 3))

treeBall_Neighbors = sklearn.neighbors.BallTree(X, leaf_size=2)
indices_Neighbors,distance_Neighbors=treeBall_Neighbors.query_radius(X[:], r=0.2,count_only=False,return_distance=True)

print(distance_Neighbors.mean())
```

It is curious because if I try to obtain the mean distance one by one, I am not getting errors:

```
print(distance_Neighbors[0].mean())
print(distance_Neighbors[1].mean())
...
```

Could you help me to obtain a  numpy array with the mean values of the neighbors without use a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you're kind of out of luck.  Let's look at what `distance_Neighbors` ends up being:

```
distance_Neighbors

array([array([0.19662693, 0.        , 0.12978415, 0.15542077, 0.19196227]),
       array([0.        , 0.10668909, 0.1864282 , 0.15770229]),
       array([0.]), array([0.14046915, 0.        , 0.19662693]),
       ...
       array([0.15770229, 0.15542077, 0.166294  , 0.08416146, 0.        ]),
       array([0.16614007, 0.        , 0.18970757, 0.19556229, 0.11739919]),
       array([0.]), array([0.]), array([0.])], dtype=object)
```

That's a ragged array, of `dtype = object` - which is not a useful datatype to do anything with in `numpy` (and when you try, they tend to be the source of strange errors such as the one you have found).  Not your fault, that's what `sklearn`'s output is, but you're kind of stuck going through it like a list because a ragged array of `dtype = object` is basically no better than a list in the first place.

As a second issue, all those arrays have a `0.0` in them that will mess with your average.  If you don't mind results with no neighbors being `nan` you can do:

```
[a[a>0].mean() for a in distance_Neighbors]
Out[13]: 
[0.1684485306859162,
 0.1502731942636554,
 nan,
 0.1685480404455817,
 0.14716664746268726,
 ...
 0.16064019067059504,
 0.17164368138912153,
 0.14089463228303245,
 0.16720227805614482,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan]
```

If you want some other way to handle them, you'll need to make a real `for` loop.  If you don't want to handle them at all, just use `[a.mean() for a in distance_Neighbors]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Thanks to it I found a way to resolve this issue. Finally my code looks like: 
`f = lambda x: distance_Neighbors[x].mean()`       
`test= list(map(f, np.arange(0, np.shape(distance_Neighbors)[0])))`
I used lambda in order to increase the speed of the process. Right now I'm managing 300M points, and this is the reason to avoid loops... Thanks again!

Comment: Other fast solution: np.vectorize(np.mean)(distance_Neighbors)